# I keep getting the java.util.NoSuchElementException but I do not see where the error lies

Tags: java, nosuchelementexception

I am trying to write a java program that reads a text file and counts the number of times each word occurs. But I keep getting the No such element Exception. I assume there is something wrong with the ArrayList or how I am accessing the elements of it. Any help would be appreciated.

```
    package text_analyzer;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Text_analyzer
{
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
  {
        File file = new File("TestFile.txt");

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(file);
        int i = 0, indexOfWord = 0, count = 0;
        List<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();
        List<Integer> wordCount = new ArrayList<Integer>();
 
        while (sc.hasNextLine())
        {
         String word = sc.next();
    
          if(words.contains(word))
          {
          indexOfWord = words.indexOf(word);
          count = wordCount.get(indexOfWord);
          count = count+1;
          wordCount.add(indexOfWord, count);        
          }
          else
          {
          words.add(i,word);
          wordCount.add(i,1);
          i++;
          }
         }
                  
        sc.close();
        
        int no_of_elements = words.size();
        for(int j = 0; j < no_of_elements; j++)
            System.out.println(words.get(j));
  }
 }
```

Comment: if you use `hasNextLine`, you should use `nextLine`, not `next`

Answer (score 0):

**Your logic is correct**;

1. Check the path of the file, and make sure it is present or add an additional check in code.
   [File Path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2MGOh.png)
2. Add exception handling for new File() method in case file is not found.

   ```
    File file = new File("C:\\work\\TestFile.txt");

    Scanner sc = null;
    try {
        sc = new Scanner(file);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
   ```

Result:  [Output result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vPE52.png)